# How to set external gradient colors and styles for React Native's LinearGradient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, typeerror

"react-native-linear-gradient" how to pass colors as props and styles also

```
interface Props {
        // gradientColors:string[]
    gradientColors:Array<string>
}

const BaseButton: React.FC<Props> = ({ gradientStyle ,gradientColors}) => {

 const styles = buttonStyle({
 btnHeight,btnWidth, btnColor, btnFont, btnTextColor, btnBorderRadius,
    })
    const gradientColorsTest = ['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']

    return (
        <LinearGradient
            // colors={['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
            colors={gradientColors}
            // style={styles.gradient}
            style={gradientStyle}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}}>
                <View style={styles.buttonViewStyle}>
                    <Text>ButtonTest</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </LinearGradient>
    )}
export default BaseButton
```

How to send colors and style externally for linear gradient.

i was tried to pass as colors={gradientColors} but it shows error of `
**** Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**** how to solve this error

Comment: Show full code, what are `gradientColors` and `gradientStyle`?

Comment: now updated the full code, please view that above

Answer (score 0):

call your `BaseButton` component this way:

```
<BaseButton
    gradientColors: {['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
    gradientStyle: {{flex: 1}} 
>

</BaseButton>
```

And in your `BaseButton` component pass the props to `LinearGradient`:

```
import { StyleProp, TouchableOpacity, View, ViewStyle, Text } from 'react-native';

interface Props {
    gradientColors: (string | number)[];
    gradientStyle: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
}

const BaseButton: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
const styles = buttonStyle({btnHeight,btnWidth, btnColor, btnFont, btnTextColor, btnBorderRadius})

return (
        <LinearGradient
            colors={props.gradientColors}
            style={props.gradientStyle}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}}>
                <View style={styles.buttonViewStyle}>
                    <Text>ButtonTest</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </LinearGradient>
    )
}
```

Comment: i tried this gradientColors = {['#4c669f', '#3b5998', '#192f6a']}
but it shows the error : cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: I don't know how but it seems that your props gradientColors is undefined

Comment: that is the problem it shows undefined and  error in npm <NativeLinearGradient colors={colors.map(processColor)} in index.android.js

Comment: now it works, i got the solution thanks for helping, the type is: (string | number)[]

Comment: Nice, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

**react-native-linear-gradient for set external gradient colors**

```
 this is not suitable for in Typescript: gradientColors: string[];

 correct format is : gradientColors: (string | number)[];
```

- react-native-linear-gradient color type is: **(string | number)[]***

this type is only accepted in typescript